# SKProductsRequest fails in Xcode version 12.1 in SKTestSession

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, storekit

When I run `SKProductsRequest` from the unit tests, I get this error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "UNKNOWN_ERROR" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNKNOWN_ERROR, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9b514849e0 {Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=950 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred}}}
```

Test

```
let session = try SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "Configuration") 
session.disableDialogs = true 
buyProduct()
```

In buyProduct() performed

```
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ids) 
request.delegate = self request.start()
```

In delegate method `func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error)` I get an error

Comment: Hi Ivan, welcome to Stack Overflow . I would be helpful if you could post the test code that is producing this error. Thanks.

Comment: Hi mokagio!
///Test let session = try SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "Configuration")
  session.disableDialogs = true
            buyProduct()

Comment: In buyProduct() performed 
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ids)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

Comment: in delegate method
func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) 
I get an error

Comment: What's the content of your store `Configuration.storekit` file? Maybe the ids are not in there?

Comment: P.S. You can "edit" your question to add code examples. It will make it easier to read for people that might be able to answer it as well as those that might have your same problem.

Comment: Yes, the Configuration.storekit file is correct. There are no mistakes when buying with the simulator. It only appears when using SKTestSession